# How to implement for each and lookup activity in a pipeline scheduled to run every 5 mins where for each picks next subsets of data recursively

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to implement a pipeline with or without lookup activity along with for each , where the for each picks up subsets of data using take([array], n) function. I have a csv file with few symbols of it. , let's say 500. Now everyday i would like to trigger a pipeline which basically does a lookup activity fetching the symbols as the input to for each activity. However i would like the for each to pick up the next subset of the ouput array(from. lookup actvity) during its 2nd execution after 5 mins and so on. The For each activity has a few data flow activities and these execute with input as subset of data from lookup activity output.
My current pipeline :

[image: current pipelines]

I have no clue how to go about this as i'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to schedule the pipeline to have the For Each activity pick up the next subset of symbols during its second execution after 5 minutes. The workaround is to add the `Wait activity`  in the for-each activity, to achieve this requirement. You can add this wait activity in the beginning or the end in the for-each activity.

- Add a Wait activity in the For Each activity
- Set the "Wait time in seconds" settings to 300 seconds.
  [image]
- This will pause the pipeline for 5 minutes before the next iteration of the For Each activity.